# PayPal buy now, get payments information

Tags: paypal

I have website with "PayPal buy now" button.
How do I automatically get the customers which to make a payment?

I need to get the price, email and product name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Instant Payment Notification](https://www.paypal.com/ipn) to receive real-time POST notifications of all transaction data that hits your PayPal account.  This will allow you to automate tasks like updating a database, sending email notifications, hitting 3rd party web services, etc.